# Connect to running MySQL database

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, odb

Is it possible to connect to a running MySQL database with odb from [codesynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/) and get read access to already existing tables?

In detail:
I want to connect to the following database that already has some tables.
Database Name: MyDB
User: Michael
Password: 123456
Host: 192.168.1.9
Port: 3306
Table names: Age, ...

```
+---------------------------------------+  
|                Age:                   |  
+---------------------------------------+  
| FirstName    LastName    AgeInYears   | 
+---------------------------------------+  
| Andy         Smith       35           |  
| Nick         Bush        36           |  
| Pete         Carrol      53           |  
| ...          ...         ...          |  
+---------------------------------------+
```

For example I want to store the maximum of the AgeInYears column in a simple double.

All odb examples start with creating a NEW database via:
    auto_ptr db (create_database (argc, argv))...

Answer (score 0):

Yes ODB supports using already existing database schemes, like yours. [See](http://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/odb-users/2013-May/001291.html)